# Can't getting the image to upload on mysql longblob

Tags: php, html, forms

When I try to upload image, its gets empty field. I don't know why.
Please help..

html form:

```
<form action="edit_profile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/formdata">
    <input type="file" name="profile_image" required="">
    <button name="upload_image" class="btn btn-danger">Go</button>
</form>
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload_image'])){
        $image = $_FILES['profile_image']['tmp_name'];
        $profile_image = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));

        $sql = "update users set image='".$profile_image."' where username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        if($result){
            echo "<script>window.open('profile.php','_SELF')</script>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<script>alert('Error!')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('profile.php','_SELF')</script>";
        }
    }
```

I getting empty image field..

Comment: Your form's ``enctype`` should be ``multipart/form-data``, not ``multipart/formdata``. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417567/uploading-an-image-to-a-mysql-database-using-a-blob

Comment: @Subham, where you declare the $username? and one more thing you have to use the type="submit" in the button

Comment: @NarendraVerma $username is my session username, I forgot to edit that in question. and if I use <input> instead of <button> then I should use type="submit"..

Comment: Saving images right in the database, yikes. I once had a database that was 250GB with images in it. It was an old site they wanted me to rebuild.  It was impossible to work with. ( actually it was a mail order bride site ... lol )

Comment: @kmoser, thank you so much.. It was typing mistake.. the hyphen in my keyboard is hard. so i pressed it lightly..

Comment: Is this just for like a small avatar type image?  You will probably be ok with that and I understand for simplicity sake, but I would be careful of saving to much data as blobs as it can quickly get out of hand and ruin your DB performance.

Comment: I understand @artisticphoenix, its a little project, therefore i am not concentrating on these issues.. thank you for replying..

Comment: Cool, I just thought I should mention the word of warning having dealt with something similar in the past.  That was circa 2010, though.  Good luck coding!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this**

You have to change from `enctype="multipart/formdata"`  to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

I added the `type="submit"` to the button. I know it's by default `submit`

**HTML code**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="profile_image"  required="">
    <button type="submit" name="upload_image" class="btn btn-danger">Go</button>
</form>
```

**Process.php**

Add your database file here

```
if (isset($_POST["upload_image"])) {
 if ($_FILES["profile_image"]["error"] > 0) {
            $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];
        }
            else if (($_FILES["profile_image"]["type"] == "image/gif") ||
            ($_FILES["profile_image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") ||
            ($_FILES["profile_image"]["type"] == "image/png") ||
            ($_FILES["profile_image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) {

            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["profile_image"]["name"]);
            $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
            //echo $newfilename;
            $url = 'upload/'.$newfilename;// it will store the image in the upload folder
            $filename = compress_image($_FILES["profile_image"]["tmp_name"], $url, 80);//this will call the compress_image fruntion for optimize the image
        }else {
            $error = "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png";
        }

 $new_image_name=$newfilename;//here is the new random file name

 $sql = "update users set image='".$new_image_name."' where  username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if($result){
            echo "<script>window.open('profile.php','_SELF')</script>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<script>alert('Error!')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('profile.php','_SELF')</script>";
        }
}
```

Below function will optimize the image.

```
  $name = ''; $type = ''; $size = ''; $error = '';
   function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {

      $info = getimagesize($source_url);

          if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);

          elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
          $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);

          elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
          $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

          imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
          return $destination_url;
        }
```